# Extending tornado.gen.Task

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, tornado

Here's the interesting bits of a stupid websocket clock:

```
class StupidClock(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = {}

    @web.asynchronous
    @gen.coroutine
    def open(self):
        self.is_open = True
        def enqueue(callback=None):
            self.__class__.clients[self] = callback
        while self.is_open:
            # This is the most interesting part!
            msg = yield gen.Task(enqueue)
            self.write_message(msg)

    def on_close(self):
        self.is_open = False
        del self.__class__.clients[self]

    @classmethod
    def periodic_update(cls):
        msg = time.time()
        # copy and clear before iterating to avoid infinite growth!
        clients = cls.clients.copy()
        cls.clients.clear()

        for obj, callback in clients.items():
            if obj.is_open:
                callback(msg)

# all the routing and application setup omitted...

loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
cb = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(StupidClock.periodic_callback, 1,
                             io_loop=loop)
cb.start()
loop.start()
```

So my question is about deconstructing this statement:

```
msg = yield gen.Task(enqueue)
```

From the documentation, it's the same as:

```
result = yield gen.Task(func, args)
# is the same as
func(args, callback=(yield gen.Callback(key)))
result = yield gen.Wait(key)
```

It's quite clear to me what's happening with the first form (only one `yield` expression), but why must I yield control to Tornado to create a `gen.Callback` object?

How can one single `yield` expression be equivalent to two `yield` expressions? Mustn't control yield to Tornado two times? Yet, in the `gen.Task` form, I only yield control once!

Comment: I haven't worked with Tornado, but it looks like the `yield` in the second example just requests a new callback function with the given key. You can look at the source, as it's pretty clean: https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/gen.py#L285

Answer (score 0):

When you call `yield gen.Callback` it briefly transfers control to Tornado, but Tornado immediately returns to your code.  It's just a way to communicate with the coroutine scheduler without using global (or thread-local) variables.  It uses this weird pattern so it can work with libraries that predated the `gen` module and don't know anything about coroutines.  For newer code (since Tornado 3.0), the recommended pattern has been for asynchronous functions to return a `Future` (which happens automatically if you use `@gen.coroutine`), which lets them be used in coroutines without `gen.Task` or `gen.Callback`.