# How to replace `yield gen.Task(fn, argument)` with an equivalent asyncio expression?

Tags: asynchronous, callback, tornado, python-asyncio, coroutine

**Problem:**
I am trying to update some old code (which I didn't write), which uses an outdated version of Tornado and [`gen.Task`](https://docs.huihoo.com/tornado/4.2/gen.html#tornado.gen.Task), to use the current version of Tornado and asyncio. This is mostly straightforward except for this one expression which (1) I do not fully understand, and which (2) I cannot figure out how to replace with an equivalent asyncio expression.

The single line of code I want to replace is of the form:

`response = yield gen.Task(fn, request)`

where the signature of the function `fn` is `fn(request, callback)`, and then later in the code (which is the method definition of a `gen.coroutine`) we run `callback(response)`. And I think `fn` may itself be asynchronous, although I'm not sure, and don't understand what the implications of that would be if it is true.

**EDIT:** Following the advice of another answer, I was able to rewrite this as

```
fn(request=request, callback=(yield gen.Callback("key")))
response = yield gen.Wait("key")
```

Of course though the release notes for Tornado 6 say that both `gen.Wait` and `gen.Callback` have been removed. Earlier versions of the documentation say that the `gen.Wait` is deprecated and should be replaced by `tornado.concurrent.Futures`, unfortunately it doesn't specify *how* to do so, especially given how `gen.Wait` requires a `key` argument, whereas `concurrent.futures.Futures` (apparently an alias for `asyncio.Future`) explicitly has *no* way to support a `key` argument. So I don't understand the claim that this is somehow replaceable.

Also `add_done_callback` seems to be inadequate for this purpose, since the documentation explicitly states that the callback can only take one argument, but `fn` has two.

Although so far what has worked best (and may actually work, provided I can make the `gen.coroutine` to `async def` transition correctly elsewhere) seems to be:

```
response = await asyncio.Future().add_done_callback(partial(fn, request=request))
```

<strike>This only produces unexpected behavior (endless blocking, seemingly probably because of the insufficient `gen.coroutine` to `async def` conversions mentioned above) and *no errors*.</strike> This gives the error `TypeError: Can't await NoneType`. So I have no clue.

**Background:** I have tried to figure out what recommendations Tornado gave when `gen.Task` was updated and finally removed. In the changelog for version 6, however, it does not say how to update our code using `gen.Task`, only that it has been removed. I have found [at least one question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655362/extending-tornado-gen-task) as well as [a Tornado GitHub issue](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1442) where it is said (without giving specific examples or implementation details) that any instance of `gen.Task` can be replaced with a `gen.coroutine`. However, since I do not understand the general concepts of asynchronous programming very well, nor the particulars of `tornado.gen.Task`, it is very difficult for me to figure out how this could be done. It would be great though since it seems to be easy to replace `gen.coroutine`'s with asyncio equivalents -- just `async def` and `await` everything.

The result of `yield gen.Task` is supposed to be, according to the documentation:

> Takes a function (and optional additional arguments) and runs it with those arguments plus a callback keyword argument. The argument passed to the callback is returned as the result of the yield expression.
>
> Changed in version 4.0: `gen.Task` is now a function that returns a `Future`...

However this seems more complicated than something that can be replaced with `gen.coroutine`, since it directly creates a `Future`, rather than `await`ing the result of an asynchronous function, and there are numerous ways to create and work with futures in asyncio, and I vaguely remember reading somewhere that Tornado futures and asyncio futures aren't actually equivalent.

The fact that this involves both asynchronous and functional programming makes the problem even more difficult to understand -- I vaguely grasp the functional part, but my understanding of asynchronous programming is very poor, to the extent that it suddenly also makes the functional aspect difficult to understand now too.

---

**What I've tried so far:**

`response = yield asyncio.add_done_callback(functools.partial(fn, request=request))`

giving the error `AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'add_done_callback'`, which, fine, I get that `add_done_callback` is supposed to be an attribute of an `asyncio.Future` object, but then what do I make/choose to be the `asyncio.Future`?

`response = yield asyncio.Task(partial(fn, request=request).func)`

which gave the error `TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got <bound method Class.fn of <SubClass object at 0x7f5df254b748>>`.

The reason I tried to use the `.func` attribute of the partial object is because when I tried:

`response = yield asyncio.Task(partial(fn, request=request))`

I got the error `TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got functools.partial(<bound method Class.fn of <SubClass object at 0x7ffaad59b710>>, request=<tornado.httpclient._RequestProxy object at 0x7ffaad4c8080>)`. But I only tried to do that because more straightforward attempts at solutions led to complaints about the number of arguments being incorrect.

In particular, trying one of the most naive things,

`response = yield asyncio.Task(fn, request)`

led to the in hindsight predictable error `TypeError: Task() takes at most 1 positional arguments (2 given)`. [The release notes for Tornado 5.0](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v5.0.0.html) say that internally all `gen.Task`'s were replaced with `asyncio.Task`'s, but this makes it difficult for me to understand how, since it looks like `asyncio.Task` is inadequate by itself to handle callbacks.

I had originally been more optimistic and hoped that `asyncio.Task` would notice that the call signature of `fn` was `fn(request, callback)`, and would then understand `fn(request)` to be the partially applied function. But of course that

`response = yield asyncio.Task(fn(request))`

gave the error `TypeError: fn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'`.

What's even more confusing is that `fn` itself is possibly asynchronous, so I thought that using `asyncio` I might just be able to partially apply it and get back an asynchronous function that takes a callback as an option

`response = yield fn(request)`

but that just led to the error `TypeError: fn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'`.

I also tried creating a task or future in asyncio (I'm not sure which of the two I need to create) using the recommended `ensure_future` and `create_task` functions, since using `Task` directly is strongly discouraged according to the asyncio docs. This did not work out well:

`response = yield asyncio.create_task(fn, request)`

giving the error `TypeError: create_task() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Using `ensure_future` led to no better result:

`response = asyncio.ensure_future(functools.partial(fn, request))`

gave the result `TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required`, and not using `partial`

`response = asyncio.ensure_future(super().fetch_impl, request=request)`

gave the error  `TypeError: ensure_future() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'`.

In case it's relevant, `fn` is the `fetch_impl` method of Tornado's `CurlAsyncHTTPClient`.

**Similar questions:** These two questions seem similar, but I don't understand how to use their answers for my problem. They probably are applicable, but again my understanding of asynchronous programming in general and asyncio in particular is very bad and I am very stupid. So an answer explaining the answers to these other two questions like I'm a five year old would also be appreciated. Any patience you can muster for my stupidity+ignorance will be appreciated.

[How does 'yield' work in tornado when making an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949173/how-does-yield-work-in-tornado-when-making-an-asynchronous-call)

[Extending tornado.gen.Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655362/extending-tornado-gen-task)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have found at least one question on StackOverflow as well as a Tornado GitHub issue where it is said (without giving specific examples or implementation details) that any instance of gen.Task can be replaced with a gen.coroutine. However, since I do not understand the general concepts of asynchronous programming very well, nor the particulars of tornado.gen.Task, it is very difficult for me to figure out how this could be done. It would be great though since it seems to be easy to replace gen.coroutine's with asyncio equivalents -- just async def and await everything.

You're focusing on "how do I call this thing that takes a callback". The problem is that the entire concept of callbacks has been deprecated and removed from Tornado, so there is no elegant way to call something that takes a callback any more. The intended path forward is to change *the thing that takes a callback* (i.e., `fn`) to use `gen.coroutine` and/or return a `Future`, and then you can call it directly from your other coroutines.

If `fn` was using `@gen.engine` (the first version of coroutines in Tornado), this is fairly easy: just replace `@gen.engine` with `@gen.coroutine` and remove any references to the `callback` argument. The function probably ends with `callback(response)`; replace this with `raise gen.Return(response)`.

If `fn` was just using raw callbacks without `@gen.engine`, then updating it to work in the modern way will be harder, and it's something that needs to be handled on a case-by-case basis so I can't give you useful guidance here.

If you're stuck with something that takes a callback and you can't change it, this sequence is **almost** equivalent to `response = yield gen.Task(fn, request)`:

```
future = tornado.concurrent.Future()
fn(request, callback=future.set_result)
response = yield future
```

The difference between this and `gen.Task` has to do with error handling. If `fn` raises an exception, `gen.Task` had some expensive magic to ensure that it could catch that exception and re-raise it in the calling function. Maintaining that magic had some performance cost even for apps that didn't use `gen.Task`, which is why it was eventually deprecated and removed (along with everything related to callbacks). So you may need to change `fn` to ensure that any possible exceptions are caught and reported appropriately (again, the recommended way to do this is to move to coroutines where exception handling works more as you'd expect).

Answer (score 2):

If you can update your function to an `async def` (and therefore use `await`), then what you need can be expressed as:

```
future = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
fn(request=request, callback=future.set_result)
response = await future
```

The "future" object can be awaited, and its `set_result` method resumes the awaitee. `fn` doesn't need to know about the future, though, it only sees a callback function.